# transparent gif help

Tags: transparency, opacity, browser

I have a website that I need to make some images that are colored, with a 45% opacity, so you can see through to the background. My problem is that for obvious reasons I cannot use a .png. I have used a gif. When I get it on the site, the opacity has read as far as the color, but you cannot see through it. How do I make this happen

EDIT

I don't want to use an IE6 hack if I don't have to. As far as I have tried, there are no scalable hacks.

Comment: What is a "scalable hack"? I'm not sure what is so terrible about the several workarounds available for IE6 to support alpha transparency in PNGs. IE6 is a hack.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GIF does not support alpha transparency. Why is it so obvious that you cannot use PNG?

PNG works in all modern browsers, whereas alpha transparency is not supported in IE6 natively. However, there are many fixes for this available on the good 'ol webernets..

If you absolutely must support "dumb users", force them to use [Chrome Frame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe), the "i'm in ur browser making ur browser another better browser" browser. Chrome Frame is a plugin for IE that renders the page using the Chromium engine from Google.

Comment: I concur.  PNG transparency works in all major browsers, it's alpha transparency that doesn't work well in IE6 and there are numerous easy fixes for it.

Comment: if you are referring to IE6's lack of PNG Alpha transparency support.. there are multiple workarounds for this that will solve 95% of the issues.

Comment: all the fixes i have tried have screwed up other things on the site...none of them are suitable for a larger website with a lot of potential transparencies...as they will slow down the loading.

Comment: Then you're SOL. GIFs cannot do what you request.

Comment: Tell your client to stop supporting IE6. http://desizntech.info/2009/02/die-ie6-die-go-to-hell-already/

Comment: haha, i wish i could...but thatd be like telling an ice cream salesman to stop supporting children clients.

Answer (score 4):

gif has only 1 bit of opacity, you can't have 45%

Answer (score 3):

GIF transparency is either all on, or all off. It does not support partial transparency. PNG however does have partial transparency support. Unless you have a specific requirement to not use PNG images, I see no reason they could not be used.

Comment: I can't use PNGs because of IE6...our user-base is highly dumb with browsers. :( ...I'm trying to stay away from hacks because they are sketchy, and often depend on the browser settings anyway (javascript)

Comment: The hacks are not "sketchy", they are functional. IE6 is sketchy. If your users are using IE6 with JS disabled, well, they're probably not having very much fun on the internet these days anyways. And in that case, you can fall back to GIF and tell the user why they have to look at an ugly user interface. Or you can force them to use chrome frame: http://www.google.com/chromeframe

Answer (score 2):

Use transparent PNG to gain the full Alpha Channel, and then a fall-back CSS for Internet Explorer 6 that uses GIF, or one of the many workarounds to support transparent PNGs in IE6 (except the "workarounds" using [AlphaImageLoader](http://www.stum.de/2008/12/01/do-not-use-alphaimageloader-to-fix-transparent-pngs-in-ie6/))

Answer (score 1):

As stated above GIF only has 1 bit opacity, meaning On or OFF, nothing in-between. That is the same as 8-bit PNG.

Assuming the reason you can't use .PNG is because you're required to to fall back and work in older version of Internet Explorer.  Unforuntately there is no good way to make it work. There are [hacks](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/making-png-image-transparency-work-in-internet-explorer/) that you can use to get PNGs to work properly in IE6, but if you have to support all the way back to IE5 you're SOL.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with different transparent GIFs, some are unstable and cause CSS glitches. For example, if you have an `<img>` and you use the tiniest transparent GIF possible, it works fine, however, if you then want your transparent GIF to have a `background-image`, then this is impossible. For some reason, some GIFs such as the following prevent CSS backgrounds.

**Short but Unstable**

`data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==`

I would advise using the slightly longer and more stable version as follows:

**Stable But Longer**

`data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7`